# How to flatten - ignore axis from a Direction Cosine Matrix?

Tags: matrix, rotation, orientation, gyroscope, rotational-matrices

Why hello thar. I have a 3D model whose starting angles along its 3 axis are known. Those angles are transformed into a Direction Cosine Matrix using this pattern ([information found here](http://www.control.aau.dk/~jan/undervisning/MechanicsI/ST8/ST8-MM2/ST8-MM1-view1.pdf)) :

[image: DCM]

New angles values are obtained as time goes by, corresponding to an update of the model's orientation. To take those new values into consideration, I update the DCM with those in this way :

```
newDCM = oldDCM * newanglesDCM
```

**What I want and how I do it :** Now the tricky part. I actually only want the Y component of the rotation matrix. In order to apply a motion on my model, I need it to be flatten so the motion vector doesn't go either in the air or down on the ground. To do so I simply pull the 3 angles back from the rotation matrix and create a new one with the angles [0 Y 0].

**The problem I have :** When rotation are applied to the model, the DCM is updated. As a motion is detected, I multiply the motion vector [0 Yvalue 0] to the DCM that has been flatten (according to the previous explanation). The result is great when the instantaneous rotations have null or close to null values in X and Z components. But as soon as the model is in a situation where X and Z have significant values, the "orientation" of the model's motion is wrong. If I apply rotations that make it return into a "only Y" situation, it starts being good again.

**What could go wrong :** Either my Direction Cosine Matrix is wrong, or the technique I use to flatten the matrix is just completely stupid.

Thanks for your help, I'd really appreciate if you could give me a hand on this !
Greg.

**EDIT : Example as requested**

My model has 3 axis X,Y and Z. This defines the XYZ convention when the model is at rest. At starting point t0, I know the angles dAx, dAy and dAz that allow me to rotate the model from its original configuration to the one it is in at t0. If that bugs you, let's say that the model is at rest at t0, it doesn't matter.

I create the DCM just like explained in the image (let it be an identity matrix if it started at rest).

Every now and then rotations are applied to the model. Those rotations also are made of a dAx, dAy and dAz. Thus I update the rotation matrix (DCM) by multiplying the old one by the newly generated one : newDCM = oldDCM * newanglesDCM.
Now let's say I want the model to move, on the grid, from a point to another. Imagine the grid to be a street for example. Whether the model is oriented towards the sky, on a side or in front of it, I want the motion to be the same : alonside the road and not elevating in the air or diving into the ground.
If I kept the rotation matrix as it is, applying a [0 Y 0] rotation WOULD make it go somewhere I don't want it to. Thus I try to find my old original XZ frame, by flattening the DCM. Then I still have the Y component so I know where in the street the model is moving.

Imagine a character, whose head is the model and who is walking outside. If he looks to a building's window and walks, he won't walk in the air right up to the window - he'll walk to the feet of the building. That is exactly what I want to do :D

Comment: This is more like a question for math.stackexchange.com
Some random guesses:
When updating the DCM, you multiply the matrices?
if yes, what about storing the Angles too and then just adding the Y rotation to the previous angles and reconstructing the matrix.
Did you count in Gimbal lock? if the problem is because gimbal lock(google it for info) then you could use a quaternion-based rotation mechanism

Comment: I really do not understand what you are trying to do. Can you provide an example, and describe your `XYZ` axes convention?

Comment: I guess that the XYZ in the matrix is the arbitary axis of rotation.
that seems a lot like rotation about an arbitary axis.

Comment: @akaltar - Yeah I do multiply the matrices, even though I don't really what you mean by adding the rotation to the angles. Gimbal lock should be avoided by using DCM (as it should be one of its main purpose after all).

Comment: @ja72 - Added some more detailed example, let me know if still not sure what I actually want !

Comment: So you have three rotations about local `XYZ` axes in sequence (like `Rx*Ry*Rz`) and you want to decompose this into a different sequence (like `Rx*Rz*Ry`) such that you can pull the `Ry` rotation angle out?

Comment: I do want to pull the Ry rotation angle out, but after a long sequence of matrix updates. I want to take in consideration all of the Rx, Ry and Rz when the model is rotation, but when I need to use that matrix for motion, I need the Rx and Rz values to be null. Or at least that's how I thought about solving the problem.

Comment: Also remember that with the DCM, the each column of the matrix correspond to the coordinates of a local axis. Usually the first column is the _x_-axis and so on.

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971558/y-rotation-from-rotation-matrix

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is equate the elements two rotation matrices

```
E_1 = Rx(dθx)Ry(dθy)Rz(dθz)
```

and

```
E_2 = Rx(dφx)Rz(dφz)Ry(dφy)
```

in an element by element basis. Find two elemetns that contain only `sin(dφy)` and `cos(dφy)` and divide them to get `tan(dφy)=...` in terms of `dθx`, `dθy` and `dθz`.

I tried to do this with the DCM given but I cannot replicate the sequence of rotations to get what you have. My `E_1` above is similar but some signs are different. In my example that I did I got the following expressions

```
dφy=atan( tan(dθy)/cos(dθz) )
dφz=atan( (cos(dθy)*sin(dθz))/(cos(dθy)*cos(dθz)*cos(dφy)+sin(dθy)*sin(dφy)) )
dφx=atan( (cos(dθx)*sin(dθy)*sin(dθz)+sin(dθx)*cos(dθz))/(cos(dθx)*cos(dθz)- ...
```

You have to work out your own relationships based on the sequences you use.

Note: that once `dφy` is known the above `E_1 = E_2` equality becomes

```
Rx(dφx)Rz(dφz) = Rx(dθx)Ry(dθy)Rz(dθz)Ry(-dφy)
```

which is solved for `dφz` and then you have

```
Rx(dφx) = Rx(dθx)Ry(dθy)Rz(dθz)Ry(-dφy)Rz(-dφz)
```

for `dφx`.