# Y rotation from rotation matrix

Tags: c++, math, 3d, matrix, rotation

Here are my axes. i dont know what to call it. (is it ZXY?)
(this is what camera sees)

[image]

i want to know plane rotation around Y axis. Currently it is 0 degree around Y.

here is what i do,

```
Matrix33 orientmatrix = body->getGlobalOrientation();
return Degree(-asin(orientmatrix[2][0]));
```

this returns incorrect angles, in counterclockwise:
 0..45..90..45..0..-45..-90..-45..0

it should be:
0...45..90..135..180..-45..-90..-135..0

what am i doing wrong?

thank you.

(this is OGRE, code is C++)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that you are using `asin`. It returns a value between -pi/2 to +pi/2, or -90 degrees to +90 degrees.

If you want a value that spans 360 degrees you need to be using `atan2`. Assuming your orientation truly is a rotation about y, you could use

```
Degree(atan2(orientmatrix[0][2], orientmatrix[0][0]))
```